# Why I could compile .NET Core 2.1 app with 2.2 and 3.1 having installed?

Tags: .net-core

My app is targeting

`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`

and `dotnet --list-sdks` returns those:

```
2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

why I could perform `dotnet publish --configuration Release -r linux-x64`?

Comment: Because .NET Core is backwards compatible, just like every .NET version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core is backwards compatible. So therefore, the newest SDKs know about older Target Frameworks. If this wasn't the case, every time a new SDK is installed in a computer and if people remove the old one to save disk space (because it is not really needed to have multiple SDKs), then their old applications would not build. So .NET Core tools need to be able to build older Target Frameworks.